# Pass PHP Variable To JavaScript In RS Forms

Tags: rsform

how can I pass this php variable to my JavaScript in RS Forms code behind?

```
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addStyleSheet("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css");
$doc->addStyleSheet("plugins/ajax/cevents/assets/main.css");
$doc->addScript("plugins/ajax/cevents/assets/main.js");
$doc->addStyleSheet("//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css");

$employee = $_POST['Time Off Request']['Employee_Name'];

$js = "jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#print-btn').click(function(){
        let employee = = <?php echo $employee; ?>;
        console.log(employee);
    });
})";
$doc->addScriptDeclaration($js);
```

Comment: More context is needed. In which file is this code? Have you tried using `get_defined_vars()` to find out which data is available to you?

Comment: @Sharky - that is in the php scripts/scripts on form display.  I have not...how would I use that?

Comment: Put it through `var_dump()`. Also do the same for `$this`.